# Trying to duplicate code in Demo for CWAC Touchlist and getting errors for Android

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I have been developing for over 10 years in languages other than Java.  I am new to the Android world, but I'm trying to dive right in.  I am trying to make a draggable list and I found the wonderful repos https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-touchlist to do the dragging and dropping of the list items.  However, I am getting an error when I am trying to @Override the drop method for the DropListener interface.  It states that:
"The method drop(int, int) of type new TouchListView.DropListener(){} must override a superclass method"

I tried to implement the way the demo utilizes the TouchList into my application, and I also copied the code exactly in another Action, and I'm getting the same error.

My code:

```
package bu.homework.shoppinglist;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

import com.commonsware.cwac.tlv.TouchListView;

public class ItemListActivity extends ListActivity {
    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT=1;

    private static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;

    private ItemsModel mDbHelper;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.item_list);
        mDbHelper = new ItemsModel(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
        fillList();
        TouchListView itemListView = (TouchListView) getListView();
        itemListView.setDropListener(onDrop);
        System.out.print("On Drop");
        // itemListView.setRemoveListener(onRemove);
        // registerForContextMenu(itemListView);
    }

   private TouchListView.DropListener onDrop = new TouchListView.DropListener() {
        @Override
        public void drop(int from, int to) {
            System.out.print(from);
            System.out.print(to);
        }
    };

    private TouchListView.RemoveListener onRemove = new TouchListView.RemoveListener() {
        public void remove(int which) {

        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        boolean result = super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.add(0, INSERT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_insert);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case INSERT_ID:
                createItem();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case INSERT_ID:
            createItem();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case DELETE_ID:
                AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
                mDbHelper.deleteItem(info.id);
                fillList();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ItemEditActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(ItemsModel.KEY_ROWID, id);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        fillList();
    }

    private void createItem() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ItemEditActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
    }

    private void fillList() {
        // Get all of the notes from the database and create the item list
        Cursor itemCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllItems();
        startManagingCursor(itemCursor);

        // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only NAME)
        String[] from = new String[] { ItemsModel.KEY_NAME };

        // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just item_row)
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.item_row };

        // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
        SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_row, itemCursor, from, to);
        setListAdapter(notes);
    }

}
```

The code isn't near complete, but my goal is to combine the functionality of the android tutorial for the notepad with the touchlist.

My question is, what am I doing wrong.  Also is there a better way to do drag and drop lists.

Thanks,
Chris Swenor

Comment: Ok I figured out why I'm getting the error.  Because it's an interface I just need to implement it and not worry about overriding it.  However for some reason my drop listener isn't getting triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be building using Java 1.5. In Java 1.5, you cannot use `@Override` with interface method definitions. They adopted that with Java 1.6.

> However for some reason my drop listener isn't getting triggered.

Nothing leaps out at me as to where you are going wrong, other than I'm not a huge fan of `System.out.print()`. You might try using breakpoints or `Log.w()` or something instead to see if the issue is simply in the logging.

Comment: Yeah I am using my debugger now.  For some reason it was not initializing so I was using System.out....which wasn't working anyway:)

Comment: Is there an easy way to check which version of Java I am using in eclipse?  I have it installed on a new MacBook Air running OSX Lion.  I had to install Java because it doesn't come with it anymore and I would be surprised if it wasn't 1.6.

Comment: The reason it wasn't getting triggered is because of how the remove action was messing with the methods.

Comment: @Chris: I'm afraid that I do not understand this comment. If there is something I need to address in code or docs, please let me know. With respect to Eclipse, I think the Java build settings are in the project properties.

Comment: I found out my problem.  Even though I had the latest Java installed Eclipse was still using the 1.5 Compiler Compliance Level.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's complaining because you're trying to override a method that doesn't exist. I think the method may be called onDrop, not drop - change it and see if it compiles. Also, if you're using eclipse, click within your drop listener definition and type control+space, and a list of methods to override should come up, I'm guessing you'll see onDrop, not drop.